# Find how much times blood is filtered in the kidney?

Tags: homework, kidney

The blood that circulates in our body is about 1/12 of our mass. If the kidneys filter 7.5 liter of blood a hour, then how many times does it filter in the kidney the whole blood of a person will mass 60kg?

Here's what my teacher did:

1/12*60=5 liter blood

0.55*5=2.75 liter plasma of blood.

The plasma is filtered 60 times is 24 hours. (how did she find that?)

24 hours ->60 times the plasma filters

1 hour -> x

x=2.5 times

Do you understand her explanation? What should I do next?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit better what the question of the exercise is?

Comment: This is what is written in my book. I don't understand either if it says find how many times the blood filters in a day or hour.

Comment: @prishila, If you feel that my answer was correct or helpful, please vote up or accept it (click on the hollow check mark you see below the voting buttons). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to dissect your teachers answer for you:

> 1/12*60=5 liter blood

no explanation required here

> 0.55*5=2.75 liter plasma of blood.

only the plasma is filtered in the kidney (the 45% cell content remains in the blood stream), so out of the 5 l blood, only 2.75 l need to be filtered.

> The plasma is filtered 60 times is 24 hours. (how did she find that?)

the kidney filteres 7.5 l per hour so if the whole blood plasma has 2.75 l, then in one hour the whole blood is filtered 7.5/2.75=2.73 times. In one day the whole blood is filtered 2.73*24=65.5 times (the numbers are slightly rounded).